# Python regular expressions and tokenization

Tags: python, regex, tokenize

I have a string "A.B.C one two three."

I have a task to tokenize this string into ["A.B.C", one, two, three], neglecting the period at the end of the sentence. I'm having trouble removing the period at the end of the sentence by itself without interfering with the A.B.C acronym.

Is there a way for me to remove just periods at the end of a sentence without affecting acronyms using python regexs?

Comment: `s.rstrip('.')` is a quick answer, though perhaps not the best depending on exactly what you need to do.

Comment: Is there always a period at the end of the string?

Comment: Do you mean `["A.B.C", "one", "two", "three"]` (note the quotes)

Comment: Yes, that was what i meant.

Comment: There isn't always a period at the end of the string. i'm tokenizing a large file with many sentences.

Answer (score 2):

```
word = re.compile(r'[A-Za-z.]*[A-Za-z]')
word.findall("A.B.C one two three.")    # => ['A.B.C', 'one', 'two', 'three']
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `.` inside `[...]` because `.` lose its special meaing inside `[..]` and match `.` literally.

Comment: @falsetru: (wince) yeah, I knew that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
line= "A.B.C one two three."
print line[:-1].split(' ')
```

may be this way as well

Comment: How bout if I just want to replace the period at the end of the sentence by ''. As in, I want it to remain a string? Thanks!

Comment: The OP said there isn't always a period at the end.  This assumes there is.

Comment: is this you wanted?

line = line[:-1]

Comment: if we don't want to assume, we should use rstrip as you referred